# Apache MINA SSHD java.security.InvalidKeyException: The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size

Tags: java, java-8, apache-mina, ssh2-sftp, apache-sshd

We are running SFTP server using Apache SSHD mina. With Java 7 , everything works fine.
But with Java 8, we are getting the below exception when any SFTP client is trying to connect.
How to fix this issue in server side with Java 8. The client can use RSA or SHA algorithms.
But server has to handle both regardless of the key size and type. I am using SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
at sun.security.provider.DSA.checkKey(DSA.java:110)
at sun.security.provider.DSA.engineInitSign(DSA.java:142)
```